# Is it believable to store information in live DNA for billion years?

Tags: internal-consistency, aliens

Imagine a civilization that approaches Kardashev II. They are deep into spacefaring, they live on a few less than one-hundred colonized worlds. They've not found evidence of other sapient life, so they believe they are alone in the galaxy.

The unfortunate news is that this civilization is dying. No amount of effort can save them, so they decided to leave a message to those who will come after them. Their scientists concluded that if they will scatter messages that will last one billion years there is a good chance somebody will find them.

Nothing natural lasts that long, so they decided to create self-replicating storage units that would feed on simple elements found on rocky planets. The best place to leave these storage units was near volcanic vents on the floor of water oceans. The storage units were small and robust, designed to survive as long as possible.

[image]

The storage unit itself was very clever. Every bit of information was used not only as a part of the message but also as an instruction for how to build some part of the unit. The idea was to prevent the storage units from replicating if they became altered (which would also alter the message) and so the altered units would be destroyed by the flow of time.

[image]

Despite the intention, after some time, storage units with changed instructions were able to replicate and survive. But, by this time, the civilization that seeded them was already long gone. So long, that even the remains of their Dyson swarms were indistinguishable from asteroids. Eventually, some of these altered storage units changed so much that they obtained consciousness, and even were able to build their own civilization. They called themselves Humans.

---

### The question

How believable it is that somebody will find Maxwell equations and some more during DNA sequencing of some ancient organism living on the bottom of the ocean?

---

EDIT: changed the wording for clarity

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146718/discussion-on-question-by-frogofjuly-is-it-believable-to-store-information-in-li); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: It is far more believable to store information in live DNA for billion of years than to have a K2 civilization just die out. Even humanity is at a point where we are almost impossible to go extinct - without the "help" of extraterrestrials. And K2 civilization is incomprehensible larger and more robust to damage. Supernova shouldn't be an issue for them. Lack of resources is a distant history, any genetic issues are easily solvable for someone who plans for storing information into DNA for billion of years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't normally appear on this site, but that **is absolutely believable and theoretically possible in "futurology"**. The concept simply extends the boundaries of current molecular evolution into protein engineering.

Check my other sites, essentially molecular evolution is a core part of what I do.

The storage units need two components (probably three) to be viable for the design, 'message' to be preserved over vast amounts of time. These are:

1. The thing encoding the replication of the DNA is engineered to minimise mutation and that is absolutely feasible by constructing a 'hyper strong *proof reading activity*' protein(s) (*italics* is the precise technical word) and probably large numbers of them. So when the 'message' mutates a set of "mutation repair" proteins kick into action" mopping up the error. This happens and would result in replicating with minimal mutation.
2. Even when the 'message' (DNA) changes, i.e. mutates, it is engineered to immediately lose functionality, thereby unable to replicate the message. That 'message' (DNA) including the mutations then dies. The 'message' that does not mutant persists and replicates, thus the mutations are always lost. It's called purifying selection and yes it absolutely happens.
3. Compensatory mutation theory - this too complicated to explain easily.

However, across the vastness of time, no matter how brilliant the molecular design and protein engineering they couldn't identify every permutation (mutation) that would overcome the purifying selection trap, i.e. mutations start persisting. The first thing the mutated message does is dump is the 'proof reading activity', i.e. the mechanism restricting it from mutating quickly. The 'message' then enters mutation 'free-fall', mutations can occur simultaneously , i.e. within the same instance of time within the same message (and that is very 'dangerous' in this context because of the way compensatory mutations work). Then it's all systems go, and upwards through the complexity of life.

So yeah points 1 to 3 we could see why the original scientists theoreticians and wet-lab were overconfident. The design looks bullet proof, but in DNA ultimately nothing is 'bullet proof'.

Cool.

---

I'd better caveat "mutation free-fall". The pure example of mutation free-fall is cancer, there's no question about that, it's no hold bars. Thats not what I had in mind ...
The phenomena where there are sudden bursts of mutations are:

- episodic selection
- periodic selection
- selective sweeps

In contrast to "purifying" or "epistatic" selection, these are systems in rapid selection, they adapt and change. True "free-fall", like cancer, the cell simply mutates itself apart.

Some references for the above 3 processes are given in the notes below. These vast research fields however.

The overconfidence is absolutely correct ... in this area for every success there's been multiple failures. It was thought infectious disease was defeated (yeah right), vaccines got rid of viruses and antibiotics got rid of bacteria ... There have been successes (smallpox was eradicated and probably polio too) but with the benefit of hindsight the original optimism definitely wasn't how its worked out. Those little microbes just keep mutating.

They're a complex issue called "neutral theory" if the "message" is only DNA but if the "message" is stored in the protein sequence that will work.

**Caveat 2**
Storing a message thats under purifying selection would be some feat, certainly at present, but it's not impossible for future generations to develop this particularly via advances in AI. This is the hardest technological feat BTW ... developing point 1 is absolutely doable now, developing point 2 we couldn't do it at present we are simply not at that level at present. What you are doing is forcing function into a  "message" and its a level of computation we simply don't have now.

---

*Further comments*

What I would look at is the preservation of bacterial 16S sequence. This can be used to build a phylogenetic tree of **ALL** bacteria. If life is 1 billion years old, then thats how long it's been around. It contains extreme sequence conservation (for 1 billion+ year). 16S is pure DNA its a much easier concept to understand. There are lots of protein genes, e.g. DNA polymerase, that have massive amounts of conservation. This however is complicated because it's about DNA->proteins and it's really hard to grasp if biology wasn't you thing. DNA polymerase was what I had in mind in the above statements and re-engineering that to leave a message and make that message central to its functionality so purifying selection will preserve it. Purifying selection has preserved these genes for however old life is on earth (1 billion years?) and maintained strong sequence conservation.

The issue is what I am proposing is beyond current technology, but it's built on current technology. Without understanding where we are now it's hard to project that into the future.

*The key I would focus on is the overconfidence in a futuristic brilliant technological solution and how that can unravel into something completely unintended.* The emotional stuff, the arrogance of brilliance. Getting into the detailed technology is going to be hard because it's spanning lots of areas with microbial evolution. For example, generating electricity in coal fired power stations, at the time it would have been brilliant (obviously a long time ago) ... now with global warming that seems a very bad idea and we don't know the final outcome.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I am very intrigued. Do you have any useful papers in mind that I can read? Can the mutation 'free-fall' be contained by harsh environment, like Movile cave or deep ocean floor?

Comment: The papers would be difficult to understand outside the field. The closest phenomena is either **periodic selection**, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK6389/#:~:text=Periodic%20selection%20is%20a%20powerful,genetic%20diversity%20to%20near%20zero , https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-27651-3_7 or **episodic selection** https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/32/5/1365/1134918 also **selective sweeps** are a bit similar and very common in bacteria. These represent a sort of "mutation free-fall", a rapid spurt of mutation causing rapid selection and large genetic diversity changes.

Comment: Stephen Jay Gould's punctuated equilibrium (he wrote loads of books) could something similar for vertebrates. The above phenomenon are simple organism that exist in a range of environments, such as bacteria. It doesn't really matter about the environment, because what is 'harsh' to us, is the perfect ecological niche to e.g. a bacteria living within a deep ocean thermal vent. The same processes will take place the bacteria attempting to outcompete each other.

Comment: I've caveated the statement "mutation free-fall", cancer is the system of absolute "free-fall" but thats not what I had in mind and a few more things. This is a really big subject area BTW.

Comment: Can you elaborate on encoding the message in proteins? The relevant research is also very welcomed. I can't understand everything, but I can pick some words to google further.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly I've made my best attempt at a more technical explanation below the final ---- line. Hope it helps. Biology.stackexchange.com would have site members who can explain this better than I.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly thanks. Just to finish https://biology.stackexchange.com will help out understand the above. They are a very friendly. There are loads of teaching specialists there. If you provide a few technical terms (above) then ask them to explain it and how far could you extend it. I personally wouldn't get involved in "searching the web" at this stage. Biology SE should help focus things and provide guidance on further reading. Some will not do futurology (could be wrong, e.g. teaching specialists). Maybe first try asking like a biology undergrad. There will be sci-fi fans, however.

Answer (score 18):

The mutation rate in human DNA is [round about](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/mutation-rate#:%7E:text=Mutation%20rates%20in%20humans%20have,expected%20in%20each%20human%20gamete.&text=assuming%20no%20back%20mutation.) 1E-4 to 1E-6. That means that in each copying of DNA, there is between 1 in 10,000 and 1 in 1 million errors in copying the sequence.

It means that, if there is no particular restorative process, the error rate is thus.

If there is a process to restore the DNA, it can be retained with extremely few errors. For example, haemoglobin seems to be extremely stable. The differences between the molecule in humans and various other species that have similar blood chemistry is very small. The usual explanation is, any mutations in this chemical tend to produce instant death.

But if a portion of DNA is not active in representing some aspect of the organism, there is no reason to expect it to be protected from the error rate. Indeed, the expected error rate will be the towards the larger end. There is no reason for the more careful error correction in DNA that is not evolutionarily important.

Thus we can expect that each generation will produce about 1 error in 10,000 letters.

How many generations since 1 billion years? Certainly millions.

Thus, any information stored in non-expressed DNA would have massive errors. The expectation is that any such non-expressed DNA would be entirely replaced many times over 1 billion years. No useful information would survive.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146717/discussion-on-answer-by-boba-fit-is-it-believable-to-store-information-in-live-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 14):

I find it unlikely. The fact that humans evolved from these storage units is proof that the medium does not have very good long-term fidelity. Clearly, these units are are unable to maintain a pristine copy of the data they encode. After a billion years, I find it unlikely that the original data would even still exist. It is simply unbelievable that the genetic code of the storage unit could be so stable as to survive with zero errors for a billion years, yet unstable enough to evolve into a highly complex sapient organism. Either the original organism can preserve its own DNA but never evolve into anything else, or allow evolution at the cost of corrupting the message.

Consider two different cases, either that the message DNA does something useful, or it doesn't. If it doesn't do anything useful at all, there isn't any evolutionary reason to keep it intact - individuals with a mutated copy of the message will reproduce just as well as ones with an intact copy, so the message will eventually be corrupted. If the DNA does do something useful, there is more pressure to conserve it, but that doesn't preclude mutations. Evolutionary fitness is very importantly a *function of the environment* - it doesn't make sense that the same organism could represent the peak of evolutionary fitness across different environments over the course of a billion years. As the environment changes over time, so do evolutionary pressures - the designed organism may have been highly evolutionarily fit at one point, but it would not remain that way unless the environment is totally static.

But even if the message did survive, it's unclear how it could be deciphered - all other organisms on the planet descended from the original storage unit and will have a traceable phylogeny of similar genomes. Simply put, the genetic code just looks like it carries the information of genetic code, not some secondary hidden meaning.

Comment: On the deciphering part: It is possible to make the message to be self-deciphering. As humans do with space messages which are sent as radio signals. The crucial part is that it is only self-deciphering if the whole message is there. If you are missing the first part(semi-prime number) it is unlikely you will be able to recover the transmitted picture.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly My issue is more why anyone would try to decipher it in the first place. The message, even if completely intact, has a specific biological function without which the original organism cannot survive. It's not some obviously non-random sequence with a seemingly hidden meaning, it's some obviously non-random sequence which has a very obvious purpose, encoding the biology of the organism. It's unclear to me why someone would expect a common genetic motif with real biological function to have deeper meaning.

Comment: This is a fair point, but that would be very peculiar to find an ancient organism that has no "dead" DNA parts, and likely to be LUCA, to have something very specific number-wise about their DNA when viewed in binary. I bet, even with no hidden message there, somebody will try to argue, and then prove, that this first organism is artificially made. Even as a (religious?) conspiracy.

Comment: “If it doesn't do anything useful at all, there isn't any evolutionary reason to keep it intact” This is more complex in reality, see [non-coding DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-coding_DNA).

Comment: @A.L That's rather my point. Even noncoding DNA is *not* an example of DNA that "doesn't do anything useful at all," which is exactly why it is highly conserved despite not directly making any protein. It's thought that virtually the whole genome has a purpose -  if there is even such a thing as DNA that truly does nothing, it's very rare. We don't have many examples of totally useless DNA, the closer we look, the more of its purpose we understand.

Answer (score 6):

**Is it believable? Yes! And no...**

We believe that a considerable amount of human DNA is dormant. It's the remains of, for example, old evolutionary changes that are no longer useful or viable, or evolutionary traits that never caught hold and were replaced by something else. We also believe that some of it is "how to build a human" DNA that has no meaning once the human has reached maturity.

That inefficiency in our genetic code is due to nature figuring us out on the fly over millions of years.

But what if an intelligent species that understood the inner workings of DNA (much better than we do today...) were to use that knowledge to create an *engineered* life form that could carry within the dormant DNA space useful information?

Yeah... I can believe that. As I mentioned in my comment, the basics of this idea have already found their way into Science Fiction in the form of the Ultimate Computer in Douglas Adams' *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" series and Star Trek: The Next Generation's episode "The Chase" where multiple species find chunks of "something useful" within their DNA and, when all those chunks are brought together, it forms a program that results in a hologram that would have been uber cool had it not been a huge disappointment.

**But the idea requires ignoring a few things to be believable**

We humans are remarkably adept at ignoring *all kinds of truth* in the pursuit of a good story. Look at politics anywhere in the world for proof. However, for the record, the weakness in this idea is that evolution is constantly happening, and the data is nothing more than "unused space" in terms of the evolutionary record that would (over millions and billions of years) become corrupt — guaranteed. The problem is that evolution is as capable of discarding something it doesn't deem useful as it is incorporating it (if you don't mind my anthropomorphising a concept).

Yes, we can say, "but the original encoding contains instructions to avoid that!" But the problem there is that you can't end up with a human in that case. You had to start with one that changed very little over the eons — a bit like alligators, only worse. You can't allow the entire evolutionary process from primordial goo to pat-my-head-and-rub-my-belly human and still "believably" retain all that information.

**[But who cares?](https://youtu.be/poxW5pFQVEw?t=54)**

I like the idea and believe it hasn't been explored to its full depth. I believe DNA is *complex enough* and still *mysterious enough* that everyone other than an actual geneticist would happily read your story and accept the premise.

And if you do a good enough job, even the geneticists will enjoy themselves... all the while wishing they could figure out how to do what you're describing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just want to point out that I do not suggest to extract the message from humans, as they are the altered ones. The idea was to find the original organisms that are still living near the black smokers.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly The problem is that the idea that the original organisms are still living near the black smokers or anywhere else is challenging. Few species survive millions of years at all and very few will make it millions of years without meaningful alterations.

Comment: @JBH I strongly second and support this answer and was about to write a similar one. This is absurdly improbable to someone that knows anything about genetics or evolution. But it could seem believable to someone without a background in those areas and is easily within willing suspension of disbelief even for the knowledgeable and even in "hard" sci-fi.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman, this answer is constructed around the improbability of extracting a message from human DNA. I agree with that. The thing to note is that the idea in the question is different.

Answer (score 4):

> Whoever wove that Message into our DNA meant it to last until we figured out how to read it—it's built inextricably into the protein expression mechanism so any organism with a corrupted copy won't be viable. It's obvious in retrospect. If a visitor wants to leave a message, why not make it a self-reproducing, error-correcting message that any sentient race would stumble upon as soon as they undertook to reverse engineer their own design?

Source: https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/sftriple/gpic.html

Comment: One issue with this is that the mechanism that does the error correcting serves no useful biological purpose and would itself suffer mutation and consequent inactivation.

Comment: @Slarty I believe that the Illustrious Author's point was that if the message got changed in any way the cell would die, and if enough cells died the organism would be non-viable. So in practice it was not a candidate for repair: it either transcribed correctly and survived, or it didn't and disappeared... and it would also disappear if damaged by a cosmic ray etc. (In any event, the story's dated 1989 so I think we should cut him a little slack.)

Comment: It is certainly sufficient to suspend disbelief for a story in a similar way to the film Jurassic Park. So I don't want to criticise the basic plot, I'm merely trying to point out what I see as the issues so the Author is aware. Whatever genetic machinery is used to control the cell killing mechanism would itself be subject to disablement by point mutation or crossover.

Comment: @Slarty you don't need a specialized cell-killing mechanism. If the message is an integral part of the cell's most basic functions, any corruption of the message is likely to result in a non-functional cell.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I think you do need a specialized cell-killing function. I'm not sure how the cells message could be an integral part of some basic function (like the gene for protein cytochrome c production for example) even changing 1 base pair would almost certainly be deadly so there's not a lot of room for smuggling in a message.

Answer (score 3):

> The storage unit itself was very clever. Every bit of information was used not only as a part of the message but also as an instruction for how to build some part of the unit. The idea was to prevent the storage units from replicating if they became altered (which would also alter the message) and so the altered units would be destroyed by the flow of time.

This is a very good start. In reality, the key parts of the ribosomes responsible for reading mRNA strands and assembling the corresponding proteins is extremely well conserved for exactly the reason stated: any major change is likely to result in different proteins being constructed or a failure to construct proteins at all, very likely making the cell non-viable.

The ribosome itself is composed of ribosome RNA bundled around a "scaffold" of various ribosome proteins. Some parts are actually pretty robust to change, as long as they don't cause any changes to transcription, but the rest of it doesn't tolerate much change at all. The ribosomes of bacteria are all very similar, and those of eukaryotes (except those in the mitochondria, which are similar to bacterial ribosomes) and archaea are very similar, and distinct in the same ways from those of bacteria ribosomes. Either it is the prokaryotes (bacteria) which have diverged, or the archaea did so before eukaryotes appeared.

However...all this is coded for with just a few thousand base pairs of DNA. The smallest known genome is of a bacteria with only 1.3 million base pairs, and only a fraction of that would be the highly-conserved cellular machinery that could store a message, and only a fraction of *that* would actually be available for storing the message. Compression would make it more likely for some error to make the message unreadable, what you'd want is instead an error-correcting encoding which will incorporate some redundancy in exchange for error tolerance. In short, the message length would probably be limited to a few kilobytes, if that.

So, Maxwell's equations? Maybe. Maxwell's equations and enough contextual information to make them actually recognizable? That'd be less believable. The location of a time capsule stashed deep inside some geologically inert lump of rock in some very long-term-stable orbit? Maybe.

Comment: Back in the day, when space was at a premium, we'd write computer code that would double up as data. Admittedly this didn't work very well, but we were just human teenagers messing about, not an advanced civilisation trying to fulfil its dying wish. So it is not implausible that a large portion of highly-conserved cellular machinery utilises such dual-purpose encoding. This gives you a bit more leeway with message length and would serve as a clear indicator that the message was deliberate.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html has a good description of this sort of thing. However, it's also the kind of thing that genetic algorithms and actual biological evolution tend to produce, so it's not really an indication of artificial origin.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant finding a sequence that on the one hand encodes critical cellular machinery, on the other it has patterns of something entirely unrelated like the fine structure constant or something. Maybe "clear" is an overstatement (after all, we all know from His Master's Voice by Lem that these things are never clear), but the coincidence would be an indication.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **highly plausible**.

Real DNA mutation rates are too high for this to work; however, that's because mutation rate are themselves under evolutionary selection for the optimal balance of energy costs of the repair mechanisms as well as the long term advantage of the organism - i.e. organisms with very low mutation rates evolve very slowly and will eventually be outcompeted, organisms with very high mutation rates degrade in fitness too quickly for natural selection to weed out detrimental mutations.

A manufactured organism could have much lower mutation rates than any extant organism, by having more repair mechanisms, and stricter proof-reading mechanisms and more redundant storage.

Comment: And the organism needs to propagate through cell division and not sexual reproduction as the sexual reproduction mixes up DNA a lot.

Comment: @DavidR Indeed. Although I assumed the asker was talking about seeding some kind of bacteria-like life, so I took that for granted

Answer (score 0):

### Frame challenge

There are two main problems your dying civilisation needs to consider while sending out a DNA message:

1. Any civilisation capable of doing all this will be well aware of DNA's mutation characteristics and how relying on natural selection to only preserve flawless copies is a fool's errand.
2. Sending a message only makes sense if you assume someone is going to read it. Anyone able to decode your message hidden in DNA will be well aware of Maxwell's equations, as they're kind of necessary to build the technology to sequence DNA. You need to put much more advanced information into it. But what if it is found by someone horrible? The more advanced the knowledge encoded is, the bigger the danger of a random recipient misusing it.

So the whole thing doesn't make sense.

Unless...

**Why not use the message to build the recipient?**

You know those self-extracting .exe files that were all the rage in the early 2000s? They were self-extracting because they contained not just the compressed data but also the code to decompress it.

So far from it being an accident, the mutation of (some of) the message into a sentient species was the aim. A sentient species capable of figuring out Maxwell's equations and analysing DNA, determining its "age" and with a deep obsession of finding out where they came from.

A species capable of finding a multitude of the most ancient copies of your message (encoding stuff much more complicated than Maxwell's equations), find and "correct" the inevitable errors that would creep in over these time scales and figure out what the "starting" DNA might have been.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The idea of Maxwell's equation is to provide means to sync math and knowledge to read the rest of the message. The rest of the message contains information for bootstrapping space travel. Your point about recipient building is interesting, but why "message leaves" did not make replacements for themselves, instead of bothering with the message? Also, the ability to create sentient creatures from thin air is too powerful for my liking, but this is a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: I don't think it matters if something horrible uses the message. It is still better than oblivion.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly It's not an ability to create sentient creatures as such. If they could do that, they could keep their civilisation going ad infinitum. It's the opposite really, it's saying: "the only process we know for sure can create sentient creatures is evolution, so let's harness it" They don't know what shape this sentient race of "humans" will take, or when they'll emerge, but they know there's a decent chance it'll happen, and all they can do is seed the process and rely on the universal desire shared by all sentient races to look into their own past to do the rest.

Comment: From their civilisation's point of view it's a kind of "reincarnation". Their physical empire crumbles but they place the seed for the next one, which will be a different biological entity, and once they decode the message, the civilisation can be rebuilt. Maybe this has already happened several times.

Comment: Heh :) The implicit idea in question is that "message leavers" created DNA from scratch as a storage mechanism. Their emergence was not the result of evolution, as evolution relies on DNA. They don't even know what evolution is.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly The issue there is the context needed to recognize Maxwell's equations for what they are. You've got a string ~100 symbols long with at most 4 repetitions of a given symbol, and those symbols themselves are encoded using a set of four nucleobases in some diffuse and redundant error-resistant manner. You'll need a lot more just to reliably identify the symbols as symbols, let alone provide enough information on how they relate to each other to make Maxwell's equations recognizable.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly evolution does *not* rely on DNA.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly Evolution most certainly does NOT rely on DNA. Any phenomenon that is capable of reproducing itself with slight imperfections while subject to selection pressures results in evolution. It doesn't even have to be a material thing, ideas evolve in much the same way living organisms do. This is the idea behind the concept of the "meme" for example.

Comment: And I would argue that evolution is such a fundamental and simple mathematical idea that any civilisation capable of carrying out a plan like this must be familiar with it. Not least of all because of its practical uses, like how we use it as a tool to create new software algorithms. Or indeed [hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolvable_hardware)

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff, biziclop: The evolution of living organisms on our planet relies on DNA-like components pretty heavily, you can't argue with that. You can generalize this process to use as optimization in software, but even being spacefaring civ it is a long shot to assume that sentient life can emerge from it. Especially if said civ appeared through a different mechanism. I would be very interested in an example of an evolutionary process that is not connected to living creatures(excluding viruses).

Comment: @FrogOfJuly Ideas and languages are two examples of evolution happening as we speak. But as I said: anything that self-copies with errors and is subject to selective pressures will experience it. Even your different mechanism. The point really is: if you're a civilisation capable of spacefaring, you will be familiar with the mathematical concept of evolution. (It's a very basic concept that was discovered on Earth well before we even knew DNA existed.) And if you're capable of engineering DNA with the express purpose of it replicating, you will know how this concept applies to that work.

Comment: And please let's not argue about this any more. You can just simply say you don't like my idea, and it's fine. After all this is your story, you don't need to justify to me or anyone why you make the creative choices you do.

Comment: @biziclop, to be fair, I like your idea :) I "argue" with you because this is a way to refine the idea in my question.

Comment: *Modern life on Earth* uses DNA, transcribing it to RNA for further processing, but there are alternatives. It is very possible that life originally used RNA exclusively, and even with the same basic sugar backbone, there's countless possible variations in the bases that could be used. Then there's alternative chains that don't use the sugar backbone. This is another possible issue...a life form engineered from scratch probably wouldn't be built with the stuff that randomly turned up in prebiotic sludge, especially if the builders were trying to make it obvious it was artificial.

Answer (score -1):

There are some challenges with storing information in DNA. DNA is not a very stable molecule over time. The Max Plank Institute had to invent new ways of reading DNA that was only 40,000 years old. The DNA was highly contaminated with DNA from other organisms. The DNA strands started fraying. And chemicals modified the DNA.

In our cells, DNA is stored behind two different walls, the cell wall and then the wall around the nucleus in order to protect it.

To have information stay encoded in DNA for millions of years, the DNA would need not just the information, but also a way to look for and fix errors. Something like how NASA uses three different computers at times in order to have enough error detection and correction. Perhaps the organism might have 3 different nuclei in each cell with error correction.

It would also help to have the information duplicated elsewhere so that a catastrophe in one location won't destroy the information. Then, you will need a way to compare stored information between the various locations and take the one that has the most votes.

Think about it. DNA has a number of ways to be destroyed. Another organism eats the cell. Chemical processes eating away at the molecule. Radiation changes the atom in a molecule which makes the information unreadable. Many other types of natural disasters will destroy the information including landslides, volcanoes, and plate tectonics subducting where this information is stored.

Edit: Storing information on the ocean floor doesn't last. Earth does not have any ocean floor older than 200 million years. Everything older than that has been subducted. Storing on land has to contend with both critters eating it and with all the processes that build dirt and rock on top of it or erode away where it is stored. In short, the DNA has to be able to move.

Comment: “Perhaps the organism might have 3 different nuclei in each cell with error correction.” Or the DNA sequence that store information can be duplicated in the same genome. For example [Polychaos dubium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychaos_dubium) has a genome 200 larger than the genome of humans, so it may be possible to add several copies of the data, without causing issues in the organism.

Comment: It is also possible to use more complex & efficient error correction codes, to be used by the civilization that would decode the message.  However, that only happens once so will have a limit how many accumulated errors it can compensate for; if the living cells themselves can do any detection/correction that's much better.